# Cannot customize different Y axis in Google bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

My google chart is made of a bar chart and a scatter chart, and so I use two different Y axis.

I cannot specify different options for each Y axis.

```
{
    vAxis: {
      /* not taken into account... */
      0: {
        title: 'Y Left Axis',
        format: '#'
      },
      1: {
        title: 'Y Right Axis',
        format: '#'
      }
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      4: {
        type: 'scatter',
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      },
      5: {
        type: 'scatter',
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      }
    },
    isStacked: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    }
}
```

If I set the `vAxis` like below, it will use the same format and same title for the two axis...

```
vAxis: {
  format: '#',
  title: 'Same title will be used for the two axis...'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not well documented but from [this page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), I had to use `vAxes` and not `vAxis`.